# Working Ctrl+X and Ctrl+V, but not Ctrl+C, in ALL apps

Tags: 14.04, unity, clipboard

I have an annoying problem with clipboard that makes me sick.

I can only copy text when cutting it. I cannot copy with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>; Also, applications *sometimes* cannot put text to my clipboard (eg keepassx) - they just clearing clipboard or so. I am not sure what causes this, could not find a solution.

My problem is not with terminal or a particular application, it touches all the system and all apps.

I have several input languages, English is at the top of the list.

**UPD:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> also not working. No solutions working.

Comment: The same with right click, copy?

Comment: @davidbaumann no, context menu is fine (the only one way for me now)

Comment: Does Shift-Ctl-C work? That's what it is in a terminal, maybe something is confused?

Comment: @zwork You must be kidding i have stated that this problem touches all apps on desktop and not connected with Terminal at all.

Comment: @DmitrijA I know, but I have seen some applications that use Shift-Ctl-C for copy, and was just suggesting it. I understand that your problem isn't connected to the Terminal, just trying to think of anything that might help.

Comment: `ctrl+C` doesn't work in KeePass if `locate-pointer` (press `ctrl+F` in DConf, then type it in) is set to true. This is a mono problem and won't solve your actual problem, however.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a shortcut bound to CTRL+C which is overriding the default CTRL+C behavior?

Comment: @kos i've checked all shortcuts in settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was the keyboard wasn't working.
I actually had symbol **`** stuck (always pressed)
that was blocking specific shortcuts like Ctrl+C, Shift+Alt+* and etc.

Thrown it out of the window

Answer (score 1):

Check your keyboard shortcuts. There may be an incorrect setting.

Comment: I checked it System Settings, all i have is 2 custom shortcuts for Shift F9/F10.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a related link to a fix for gnome-terminal. It might work for you too though:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18589/ctrlc-does-not-work-in-gnome-terminal

Courtesy of Soren:

`stty sane`
and see if it fixes the problem, also check if the intr is set correctly using:

`stty -a`
If you find that intr is set to something different than ^C, then you can also fix it by typing

`stty intr ^v^c`

Comment: >" This did not help. stty -a shows "intr = ^C" ( without the quotes) "

Comment: Also, Ctrl+C seemed to work when i enabled Caps Lock - i didn't notice this before, it worked with capital C. But then i entered second command and now nothing works again.

Comment: Strange. What happens when you type the letter "c" in lower case and with capslock turned on? Also, what language are you currently in? Russian or Czech? I'm not 100% sure but i think S is C in Russian? Not sure if this affects the key config though

Comment: As it should be, cC

Comment: It's an english C. Keyboards are Russian and pinyin(but removed already)

Comment: What happens when you open Keyboard Layout Chart (from menu Language Indicator) and press CTRL + C? Does it register at all?

Comment: No it only catches Control key (not Ctrl+C), while C alone works.